# Use value of a dropdown field for an `include`

Tags: drop-down, include

I'm trying to have this include be updated by the option I choose in my dropdown.

```
{% include 'subnav_programs.html' %}
```

My dropdown is called entry.dropSubsection

I put `{% include '{{ entry.dropSubsection }}' %}` in my html file but it keeps giving me errors.

I get this error:

> Unable to find the template “{{ entry.dropSubsection }}”.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to (more specifically, you *can't*) nest Twig tags within other Twig tags. Ditch the inner Twig tag and its respective quotes, and just pass the variable directly into the outer Twig tag...

```
{% include entry.dropSubsection %}
```

That being said, I'm not sure this will achieve exactly what you're looking for. You may need to append `.value` as well...

```
{% include entry.dropSubsection.value %}
```

Comment: Im still getting errors : Unable to find the template “{% include 'subnav_programs.html' %}”.

I'm not sure its processing the quotes outputted from the dropdown properly.

The dropdown value is:  'subnav_programs.html'

Comment: That error message seems wrong, it should simply say `Unable to find the template “subnav_programs.html”.` If it's really spitting out the full Twig tag, then it looks like you are `include`ing a whole other `include` tag.